SAP Composable 2211.19 ProductListComponentService.model$ returns null
We are currently upgrading our system from Spartacus 4.3 to Composable 2211.19. We ran into a problem in PLP. the ProductListComponentService.model$ is returning a null. Why is this happening?
it will not trigger the search API.
I even manually call the search API but it does not trigger
getProductPLP(): Observable<any> {
    debugger;
    return this.http
      .get(this.occEndpointsService.buildUrl(`products/search?fields=FULL`), {
        headers: this.headers,
      })
      .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.errorHandl));
  }

Please advise

it will not trigger the search API. Please advise

Answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78333359/sap-composable-2211-19-productlistcomponentservice-model-search-api-not-trigger
