SAP Composable 2211.19 ProductListComponentService model$ search api not trigger in PLP page
We're in the process of upgrading our SAP Composable storefront to version 2211.19. However, we've encountered an issue where the model$ from ProductListComponentService in OOTB is not triggering the search API on the PLP page. This functionality worked correctly in SAP Composable 6.8. Any insights on why this might be happening and how to address it would be appreciated. Thank you.


Heres the answer for my question:
Affects: PLP page
Cause: The basesite API call was missing the plp category code parameter.
We customized the call to the basesite API instead of using the out-of-the-box (OOTB) method.
Solution: We've added the plp category parameter to ensure that the search triggers in the plp.
protected readonly customerendpoint =
    'basesites?fields=baseSites(uid,defaultLanguage(isocode),urlEncodingAttributes,urlPatterns,stores(currencies(isocode),defaultCurrency(isocode),languages(isocode),defaultLanguage(isocode)),theme,defaultPreviewCatalogId,defaultPreviewCategoryCode,defaultPreviewProductCode)';

